# Up arrow key wih Pexpect, Python

Tags: python, flask, pexpect

How can I send a up arrow key with Python module pexpect? I have tried this:

```
child.send("\033[A")
```

but it will not work..

Comment: Do you mean up arrow key?

Comment: That is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use two sends. First to send the code for the shift key, and another to send a lower case a.
It may work if you send them together as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
child.send('\x1b[A')
```